# How much cream should I make for my mini Oreo cream pies?

Tags: pie, cream

I'm making mini cream pies, in custard cups, and I just need to know how much cream to make to fill them all.

Comment: Oreo cream pies are no bake pies. It honestly just depends on how much to want to be in it.

Answer (score 1):

You could estimate by filling the cups with water about the level you want the cream to be at, then dumping into a big measuring cup. You'll end up with a bit of extra cream that way unless you compensate for the space the crust is going to take up, but wouldn't be too far off!